# MySQL Select rows that meet specific condition

Tags: mysql, select

I have table `orders` that does look like this:

```
order_id | item_id | quantity
     1        1         2
     1        2         5
     2        3         13
     2        4         5
     3        3         1
```

I do want to SELECT all rows, but I'd like to skip entire orders that does contain exactly 13 items of item_id 3. In this example it should skip rows with order_id=2. Is it possible to do with one simple query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to find any orders that don't have 13 items of `item_id` 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM orders o2
                  WHERE o2.order_id = o1.order_id
                    AND o2.item_id = 3 
                    AND o2.quantity = 13)
```

Output:

```
order_id    item_id     quantity
1           1           2
1           2           5
3           3           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bJYm28pgWF6Nj5hNf5Hjac/0)

Comment: The NOT EXISTS method seem to work as intended - many thanks! Just wanted to add one concern: I've read that nested SELECT querries are not good for preformance. Should I be worry about this in this case?

Comment: @Zorann no - a not exists query is almost always the most efficient way to do this sort of query